# Convergence of series via ratio test

Tags: convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I am attempting to show that a sequence which I defined as $\{a_n\}$ where $a_n =\sum_{p=0}^{n}\frac{x^p}{p!}$ converges, in order to do so I have attempted the ratio test at which point I arrive at the term $a_n =\sum_{p=0}^{n}\frac{x^p}{p!}$ and $a_{n+1} =\sum_{p=0}^{n+1}\frac{x^p}{p!}$ then taking the ratio I arrive at $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{\sum_{p=0}^{n}\frac{x^p}{p!}}{\sum_{p=0}^{n+1}\frac{x^p}{p!}}$$

Taking the limit of the above is proving to be difficult. I am attempting the ratio test is . If this prove impossible I would like to show that it converges in some other form.

I have proved that in the case that $x=1$ we have convergence because it is bounded above and is increasing, however I want to show it for this case or for all x? How can we show this?
I have also thought about showing it is cauchy in some form which would imply that it is convergent.

Comment: The ratio test is between consecutive *terms* of a series, not consecutive partial sums. You must take the ratio of $x^{n+1}/(n+1)!$ and $x^n/n!$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @runway44 each term of the sequence is a sum by definiton of my sequence, would that not be improper since what you suggest implies the sequence is $a_n=x^{n+1}/(n+1)!$ which is not what I defined

Comment: I know. Testing if that sequence of partial sums converges is the same as testing if the corresponding infinite series converges is the same as testing the ratio of consecutive terms of said series.

Comment: @runway44 I saw somewhere that that was erroneous, I thought the same which would facilitate the proof. I was informed that a limit converging does not imply that the sum converges, or the convergence of the terms does not impy the sum converges

Comment: The limit of terms of a series converging dose not imply the series converges, true. But I never said otherwise.

Comment: @runway44 yes I agree, i meant to say that I was told that ratio test that you suggest does not equate to the ratio test of the two sums I give. I proved it as you suggested but a professor at my university stated it was not equivalent.

Comment: If you're saying your professor told you that you shouldn't be taking the ratio of partial sums, and it's not the same as taking the ratio of terms (of the series) which is the correct way, then your professor is correct. Otherwise I can't figure out what you're saying.

Comment: @runway44 I meant to say that for this proof I did what you are suggesting, that is for the defined sequence I took the ratio test of the terms in the way that you are suggesting, but my professor said this was not equivalent to showing the sequence of sums converges

Comment: Showing the ratio of terms of the series tends to $0$ proves the sequence of partial sums converges. Either you've misunderstood your professor, your professor misspoke, or your professor is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following are equivalent (by definition of series convergence):

**(I)** The sequence $\displaystyle\big(\sum_{p=0}^n \frac{x^p}{p!}\big)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ of partial sums $\displaystyle\sum_{p=0}^n \frac{x^p}{p!}$ of the infinite series $\displaystyle\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^p}{p!}$ converges.

**(II)** The infinite series $\displaystyle\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^p}{p!}$ converges.

The latter is implied by the following:

**(III)** The limit $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{x^{n+1}/(n+1)!}{x^n/n!}\right| $ exists and is less than $1$.

The implication **(III)** $\Rightarrow$ **(II)** is an application of the ratio test:

**Correct Ratio Test**. An infinite series $\displaystyle\sum_{p=0}^{\infty} t_p$ converges if $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}|t_{n+1}/t_n|<1$.

You seem to be misinterpreting the ratio test as follows:

**Wrong Ratio Test**. An infinite sequence $(s_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ converges if $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}|s_{n+1}/s_n|<1$.

You seem to be applying this wrong ratio test with $\displaystyle s_n=\sum_{p=0}^n\frac{x^p}{p!}$.

Comment: where you say the wrong ratio test, so the way that I am applying it cannot be done? Therefore the sequence I defined cannot be shown using the ratio test?

Comment: You are not applying the ratio test correctly. The sequence you defined *can* be shown to converge with the ratio test. You just have to use it correctly! Indeed, **(III)** is how you apply the ratio test.

Comment: Okay but I did 3 and my professor said it was improper

Comment: What do you mean by "improper"? (III) is exactly the ration test! Some more details are needed here

Comment: @imranfat I took the limit of the ratio as suggested by runway44 and concluded that it meant that $\{a\}$ as I define it above was convergent. But my professor said that I needed to do the ratio of the partial sums(sum to n+1/sum to n) and take the limit of that. And stated that the way I took the limit did not show the sequence I defined to be convergent

Comment: If you've accurately represented what your professor said, then your professor is wrong.

Comment: I am not sure if your professor is correct then. As stated, the Ratio test is not about partial sums

Comment: my reasoning was  pretty much what you have proposed @runway44 I am now trying to prove it without the ratio test

Comment: Hey thanks alot you were a great help